# Removing win xp after installing win 8

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-8, multi-boot

I've win xp and win 8 installed at the same time (dual-boot) and now I'm thinking about removing windows xp and just keep windows 8 for the usage,

The problem is that I'm unsure how to proceed on with the process or even using what terms should I google for a tutorial of such nature..

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove XP from dual boot](http://superuser.com/questions/191735/remove-xp-from-dual-boot),[Vista & XP Dual Boot - Removing XP](http://superuser.com/questions/10986/vista-xp-dual-boot-removing-xp), [Removing Windows XP from dual boot](http://superuser.com/questions/354706/removing-windows-xp-from-dual-boot), [Returning from Dual-boot to just Windows](http://superuser.com/questions/1138/returning-from-dual-boot-to-just-windows).  I searched SU for "dual boot remove XP".

Comment: How have you partitioned this system?

Answer (score 0):

If you installed Win 8 after win xp then the win 8 bootloader has probably taken over. You can just format your XP drive!

Comment: Nope they are both working at the same time and I don't know how to uninstall a window actually without formatting the whole drive, have not worked a lot with dual-boot

Comment: What do you mean by they are both working at the same time?

Comment: I can boot either of them from the boot menu, they both show up there

Comment: Yeah that's normal.. You have installed them both on different drives right? You can just boot into Windows 8 and format the Windows XP partition

Comment: Yep they are in seperate drives, I'll try that now. Thanks :)